# Entity framework run direct query

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm thinking about using Entity Framework in an ASP.NET application, using an Oracle database.
I would also need to know is I can run a query directly on the database tables and data, using Entity Framework, without using the classes and the mappings.
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ExecuteStoreQuery can be used.

However, part of the beauty/fun/elegance of using Entity is being able to write your queries using LINQ and not having to write actual SQL statements.

Also, just because you decide to use Entity, doesn't mean you can no longer use SqlCommand objects etc...

Comment: The problem is EF (as for 2011) is still heavily "under construction" and it can cope only with very simple LINQ (it does not even support indexing local arrays with constant!). So there are times it is better to run manually crafted query re-using EF connection to DB.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [ExecuteStoreQuery()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487208.aspx) for that. Be aware though that you a have to provide a type that all returned columns can be mapped to, it does not have to be an entity though.